# In a google sheets query, replace all diacritic caracters with a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to be able to search with "contains" in a query, but without being case or diacritics  sensitive. For the case sensitivity, I've found how to fix that, but for the diacritics, it's pretty difficult.

My plan here is to use an arrayformula in the range of the query request to replace all diacritics caracters by their corresponding non-diacritics caracters (they are in a two columns range I c/c from this project https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJ4YmvkvmSlUr9mXGR9HadyJanQWw6DXbNFuCApgIr4/edit#gid=0). I stored this in the range R2:S342.

But to construct this arrayformula is pretty difficult.

I am testing it in the range of data P5:P8, containing these 4 cells:
café
àéïôù
àéïôù
àéïôù

I would expect my formula to give me :
cafe
aeiou
aeiou
aeiou

But what I actually have is :
ceio
ceio
ceio
ceio

Which is the first caracter of the first cell, then the second caracter of the second cell, then the third caracter of the third cell, etc...

Here is the formula I have right now :

```
=ArrayFormula(
   If(
      IsBlank(P5:P8); "";
      Join("";
         iferror(
            Vlookup(
               Mid(P5:P8; Row(Indirect("1:"&Len(P5:P8))); 1);
               R2:S342;
               2;
               False
            );
            Mid(P5:P8; Row(Indirect("1:"&Len(P5:P8))); 1)
         )
      )
   )
)
```

When I do it on a single cell, it works ("café" -> "cafe"), but not on a range.

How could I make it work the way I want ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this already solved with the custom gas function you seem to be using in the sheet?!

Comment: For this case, I want to do it without using google apps script. I want to find a solution just with a formula.

Comment: Is `R2:S342` mentioned in the above formula the `replacement_table`?!  are we not gonna use the gas function in here as well...

Comment: Yes, R2:S342 is the replacement_table. And no, I don't use the gas function here. I would like to do it only by formula, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=let(Λ,reduce(wraprows(,4,),sequence(2),lambda(a,c,{a;importhtml("https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html","table",c)})),
   map(A:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,index(let(Δ,mid(Σ,sequence(len(Σ)),1),
           join(,xlookup(Δ,index(Λ,,2),index(Λ,,3),Δ))))))))
```

- [*this is the source*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_chars_mapping.html) I used as a backend data dump for the diacritic-character mapping but you are welcome to use a different\robust one just in case...

[image]

**Updated formula (*`to take into account case-senitivity`*)**:

```
=map(P5:P8;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);
           join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It helped me a lot. I modify a little bit your formula, and it worked almost exactly as I want to :

=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(let(Λ;{R2:S342};map(P5:P8;lambda(Σ;IF(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;MID(Σ;sequence(LEN(Σ));1);join(;xlookup(Δ;index(Λ;;1);index(Λ;;2);Δ)))))))))};"select * where Col1 is not null")

Almost because diacratics are replaced with their lower-case match instead of their upper-case's. For example, "cafÉ" becomes "cafe". with your html table, I understand why, but with my replacement table, I don't understand why É is misread with é (row 56 instead of row 57).

Comment: Added updated formula version in the answer(to fix the `é /É` issue. please do test it out.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Install an addon I created called [Flookup Data Wrangler](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/flookup/593806014962).
It is a paid add-on but you can use this particular feature for free, without need to register or subscribe.

To remove diacritics in bulk, as in your example, choose a new cell and type this [NORMALIZE](https://www.getflookup.com/documentation/spreadsheet-functions#h.6m0evbs0c19y) formula:

```
=NORMALIZE("diacritics",$P$5:$P$8)
```

If you would like to process more text, you can use the [menu function](https://www.getflookup.com/documentation/preprocess-data#h.h2hhwtmh510c) version of NORMALIZE.

**BONUS TIP:** This function can also be used to remove punctuation marks and unwanted portions of text entries.