# In Sheets, query formula with numerous columns range, but only one with a treatment on it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import, with a query formula, a range of data : O5:Q8.
In this range of data, I want to do a treatment on the P column without changing the master data, but only in the result of the query, and to import O and Q columns data unchanged. Having all in one query, to allow me to filter it easily later.

So from this data range :

| date | text | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/12/2022 | Café | 2 |
| 01/12/2022 | trÉs choûetté | 10 |
| 02/12/2022 | àéïôù | 7 |
| 03/12/2022 | É | 3 |

I would like to obtain :

| date | text | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/12/2022 | Cafe | 2 |
| 01/12/2022 | trEs chouette | 10 |
| 02/12/2022 | aeiou | 7 |
| 03/12/2022 | E | 3 |

The formula that modifies correctly the P column is this one :

```
=map(P5:P8;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);
           join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))
```

It comes from this topic : [In a google sheets query, replace all diacritic caracters with a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135999/in-a-google-sheets-query-replace-all-diacritic-caracters-with-a-formula)

But I can't figure out how to, using just only one query formula, import O P and Q columns treating P column data without changing O and Q columns.

The query I have for now is :

```
=QUERY({O5:O8;Q5:Q8;map(P5:P8;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);
           join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))};"select *")
```

But the result is in only one column and twice the length of my range :

30/12/2022

01/12/2022

02/12/2022

04/12/2022

01/01/1900

09/01/1900

06/01/1900

02/01/1900

What query formula could do what I want it to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
=QUERY({O5:O8\
        map(P5:P8;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))\
        Q5:Q8};"select *")
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I need to apply this one formula on the same O5:Q8 range on two sheets. I tried : 
`=QUERY({{Sheet1!O5:O8;Sheet2!O5:O8}\ map({Sheet1!P5:P8;Sheet2!P5:P8};lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))\ {Sheet1!Q5:Q8;Sheet2!Q5:Q8}};"select *")`
 But it gives me only the content of Sheet1, not Sheet2. How can I extend the range to numerous sheets please ?

Comment: your formula looks good to me. If possible please do share a sample sheet recreating this scenario so as for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: I understood my mistake. I was doing : `=QUERY({{Sheet1!O5:O;Sheet2!O5:O}\ map({Sheet1!P5:P;Sheet2!P5:P};lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;index(let(Δ;mid(Σ;sequence(len(Σ));1);join(;map(Δ;lambda(Λ;xlookup(1;--exact(R2:R342;Λ);S2:S342;Λ)))))))))\ {Sheet1!Q5:Q;Sheet2!Q5:Q}};"select *")`. The range were 'opened' at the end, so the data from Sheet2 where after row 1000. I just added `where Col1 is not null" at the end of the query, and it fixed the problem. Sorry for the troubles.